# Regular expression to replace (") with (\")?

Tags: java, regex

Why does the following not work:

```
      String test = "hello\"world".replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
      System.out.println(test);
```

What I'm trying to do is replace any occurrence of `"` with `\"`.

So I want to get as output:

```
hello\"world
```

Comment: You're escaping the `"`.  Try `.replaceAll("\\"", "\\\"");`

Comment: This does not even compile...

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regular expressions are overkill for this.

```
myString.replace("\"", "\\\"")
```

should do just fine and is more readable to someone familiar with the core libraries.

The [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method just replaces one substring with another.

> Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for example, replacing `"aa"` with `"b"` in the string `"aaa"` will result in `"ba"` rather than `"ab"`.

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Yes, I agree! An obvious, but probably easily overlooked solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
String test = "hello\"world".replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
System.out.println(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to two more `\\` to escape the escape character, for a total of 5 `\`s.

`\\` - escape the escape character

`\\` - to display the character

`\` - to escape the quote.

Try:

```
String test = "hello\"world".replaceAll("\"", "\\\\\"");
```